Saying Bee-bee-cue verbally
How common is it for someone to verbally say “bee-bee-cue” instead of “barbecue” in English-speaking countries (for example: Australia and United States)? In all my life, when living in both countries, I had only heard “barbecue”, and only last month, did I hear a lady say “bee-bee-cue” sauce to me for the first time in my life. Barbie is a slang used in Australia for barbecue, and I had only heard it in the phrase “shrimp on the barbie”. I know in written language, it is common in both countries to say “BBQ” sauce over “barbecue”, but never verbally. Even in tv series and films, never heard “bee-bee-que” lol.

I have never heard it used.  Either the person who said Bee Bee Que was joking or was unaware that it's short hand for barbeque.

Yeah, she was aware that it’s shorthand for barbecue. I said “this isn’t the typical barbecue sauce you find in kfc or McDonald’s”. Then she said “Yeah, we have our own bee-bee-que sauce, that is different from McDonald’s or kfc.” This took place in Australia. Are you in America or Australia? She didn’t look like she was joking lol, but her accent was weird. When I talked about chips (French fries to people outside Britain and Australia), her accent sounded weird when saying “chips” as she said “cheaps” lol.

In the UK, I think just about everybody knows that 'BBQ' stands for 'barbecue'. But this is opinion based.

Yeah, but I am talking about verbal conversation. Have you actually heard anyone in UK say “bee-bee-que” instead of “barbecue” verbally?
In writing, people tend to use “bbq” the most in all English-speaking countries, but what about for verbal conversations?

As both terms have three syllables, there's no reason to use the abbreviation in speech.

Pretty common in Canada to hear someone say "We're having a BBQ this weekend if you want to join us." or something like that but honestly it's mostly written and only said in an attempt at being cute.
